# Cumulative Sum in a column

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to run a cumulative sum for a matrix of variable size to be output  to another sheet for further analysis. These cells need to be offset by 1 row and 1 column as well as the new top row assigned a "0" value. such as shown below (done by manual calc)

[image: Manual analysis]

I am struggling to develop the code for this however what i have is shown below.

```
'Private Sub LGMethod_Click()
'Declare Variables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
'Clear Worksheet
    Worksheets("LG").Cells.Clear
'Loop to count and and analyse
    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For J = 1 To Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Worksheets("LG").Cells(i + 1, J + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Data").Range.Cells(1, i))

        Next
    Next
End Sub'
```

Comment: `=Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Data").Range.Cells(1, i))`  this is not a cumulative sum, this is similar to saying `Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, i)).value`

Comment: Okay can you suggest a method to sum this range then?

Comment: What you want basically is Skl = Sum(Aij) for i = 1 to k and j= 1 to l, is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see from your example, you want to shift down one row and calculate at each cell the cumulative sum on the column.

```
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, nRows As Integer, nCols As Integer
  With Worksheets("Data")
     nRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     nCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     Worksheets("LG").Cells.Clear
     For i = 1 To nRows
        For j = 1 To nCols
            Worksheets("LG").Cells(i + 1, j) = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(1, j), .Cells(i, j)))
        Next
     Next

     For j = 1 To nCols + 2
        Worksheets("LG").Cells(1, j) = 0
     Next
   End With
```

Comment: Seems to be running well. Thanks!